# Irregularities in Gforth's conversion to doubles

Tags: forth, gforth

I'm fairly confused about how the `s>d` and `d>s` functions work in Forth.

From what I've read, typing `16.0` will put `160 0` on the stack (since it takes up two cells) and `d.` will show `160`.

Now, if I enter `16 s>d` I would expect the stack to be `160 0` and `d.` to show `160` like in the previous example. However, the stack is `16 0` and `d.` is `16`.

Am I entering doubles incorrectly? Is `s>d` not as simple as "convert a single celled value into a double celled value? Is there any reason for this irregularity? Any clues would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Gforth interpets all of these the same: `1.60`, `16.0`, and `160.`, i.e. **160** converted to a double number.  Whereas `16 s>d` converts **16** to a double number.

ANS Forth only mandates that when *[the text interpreter processes a number that is immediately followed by a decimal point and is not found as a definition name, the text interpreter shall convert it to a double-cell number.](http://lars.nocrew.org/dpans/dpans8.htm#8.3.2)*  But Gforth goes beoynd that: http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Number-Conversion.html#Number-Conversion